# Another question in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

Question: Let $H$ be a graph of order 10 such that $3\le d(v)\le5$ for each vertex $v$ in $H$ [where $d(v)$ is the degree of $v$]. Not every vertex is of even degree. No two odd-degree vertices are of the same degree. What is the size [number of edges] of $H$?

Answer: Size of $H$ is 20

let $V(H)=\{{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j\}}$, then
$$d(a)=3,
d(b)=4,
d(c)=4,
d(d)=4,
d(e)=4,
d(f)=4,
d(g)=4,
d(h)=4,
d(i)=4,$$
$$d(j)=5$$

---

Sum is 40

hence size is 20

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you only have the possible degrees 3, 4 and 5. There's at least one odd degree vertex (so there must be at least two), but no two odd-degree vertices can have the same degree, so there must be exactly one of degree 3 and one of 5. Then the rest must be degree 4.

Comment: There's a step missing from the argument in Luke's argument.  It's also necessary to show that such a graph does indeed exist; presumably by drawing it (or describing it fully).

Comment: a little bit more practice will clear my concepts... thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

You've done all the hard work. Now all that remains is to show that such a graph exists.

*Solvitur ambulando*:

[image]